# Spring constructor injection with lots of fields

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring component that has 8 members.

I am currently autowiring these 8 members with field injection.

I now want make these members private final, and do constructor injection to set them.

This is easy enough to do, but now I have a component constructor with 8 parameters.

I know I can use setter injection and set these values in an XML file, but this I don't want to do.

Are there any other alternatives?

EDIT:

This component just does a single thing. But that involves calling several other services. Hence the 8 injections

Comment: If you do it with setters, then they can't be final.

Comment: Good point - I tried that and forgot that that wasnt an option ;)

Comment: Use Lombok to generate the constructor for you?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You want to change to constructor injection but without constructor? If the problem is only about code appealing, you can use Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation  https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: @WinterN no I want to use a constructor - but having so many args is a little unwieldy.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for the tip about constructor injections with lombok. I found a useful guide here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, there is no alternative.
Secondly, if a contructor has 8 parameters, it is not designed  properly. I think you should rethink about the class structure and responsibility. Consider splitting the class into two or three separate beans and inject those.

If a constructor has 8 arguments, in most cases it will be vioalating SRP(Single Responsibility principle)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option if you are happy to introduce Project Lombok. Given the following class:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ThankingService {

    private final Translator translator;

    public String produce() {
        return translator.translate("thank you");
    }
```

}

The Lombok annotation @RequiredArgsConstructor will cause Lombok to generate a constructor, this happens if there is 1 data variable or 10, etc.

```
@Component
public class ThankingService {

    private final Translator translator;

    public String thank() {
        return translator.translate("thank you");
    }

    /* Generated by Lombok */
    public ThankingService(Translator translator) {
        this.translator = translator;
    }
}
```

More info: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can set the initial values of these parameters in an .properties file and then read this property file as a pojo configuration class and it is very easy in spring to convert .properties file into pojo.

so the constructor will be something like this

@Autowired
public Temp(ConfigPojoClass config) {
.....
}